# Converse of "a parallel form is closed and co-closed" on Lorentzian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let's work on $(\mathcal{M},\texttt{g},\nabla)$, an $n$-dimensional [Lorentzian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold) $\mathcal{M}$ with [metric tensor field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) $\texttt{g}$ and [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) $\nabla$. Let $\{e^{a}\}$ denote a $\texttt{g}$-orthonormal cobasis with dual  $\texttt{g}$-orthonormal basis $\{X_{a}\}$ satisfying $e^{a}(X_{b})=\delta^{a}_{b}$.

Consider a $p$-form $\alpha$ on $\mathcal{M}$, then it is straightforward to show that if $\alpha$ is $\nabla$-*parallel* (i.e.  $\nabla_{X}\alpha=0$ for all vector fields $X$) then $\alpha$ is both closed ($d\alpha=0$) and co-closed ($\delta\alpha=0$), where $d$ is the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) and $\delta$ is the [co-derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Codifferential). This follows immediately from the relations between $d$, $\delta$ and $\nabla$:
\begin{align*}
d \,\equiv\,e^{a} \wedge \nabla_{X_{a}}  \qquad\text{and}\qquad \delta \,\equiv\, (-1)^{n+1}i_{X^{a}}\nabla_{X_{a}} 
\end{align*}
where $X^{a}=\texttt{g}^{ab}X_{b}$. However, it is *not* true that every closed and co-closed $p$-form is covariantly constant (it is straightforward to find examples of this). So my question is the following:

> *What conditions are required (if any such conditions exist) such that a closed and co-closed $p$-form $\alpha$ is $\nabla$-parallel* on $\mathcal{M}$?

I am assuming something like "a closed and co-closed $p$-form is $\nabla$-parallel if $\mathcal{M}$ is flat", but have no idea of where to look or how to prove any sort of conjecture on this. I guess an answer on a Riemannian manifold would be just as interesting (and may give an idea at the result on a semi-Riemannian manifold). Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at Bochner’s theorems and posts like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551261/is-there-any-bochner-technique-type-for-two-forms)?

Comment: Thank you kindly for the reply @TedShifrin. The post you mention is the one I have spent the most time on actually (and have ordered the book by Petersen which looks very useful!). It is, of course, on _Riemannian_ geometry and I need to go through it carefully to see precisely where applying it to semi-Riemannian geometry may fail or needs to be altered.

Comment: You might also find [Wu’s book](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=CTM/6) very useful. He writes beautifully.

Comment: Excellent - thank you. It certainly looks like a good resource and hopefully will help with my question.